# Convert from QByteArray to array of double

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, reinterpret-cast, qbytearray

I have an array of `double`:

```
QVector<double> Y(count);
```

I need to pack it to `QByteArray` to send via Ethernet.

So I did it. It was not too hard:

```
QByteArray line;
line.clear();
line.append(QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(Y.data()),
count*sizeof(double)));
```

I try use this code to unpack the data from `QByteArray recv` :

```
QVector<double> data((line.size())/sizeof(double));
QByteArray dou(sizeof(double),0x0);
for(int i = 0; i<data.count(); i++){
    dou = recv.mid(i*sizeof(double),sizeof(double));
    data[i] = *reinterpret_cast<const double*>(dou.data());
    dou.clear();
}
```

But I don’t like it. I want  to find out elegant way to unpack from `QByteArray` to `QVector<double>`
Can you help me?

Comment: Note: this is not just not elegant, it’s also fragile and non-portable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use a `QDataStream` which will encode the data in binary in [a specific format.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/datastreamformat.html) (more specifically first the number of items (int32) and then each item)

`QVector` has [overloads for the stream operators](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html#operator-lt-lt-43)

```
QByteArray line;
QDataStream stream(&line, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << y;
```

and to read:

```
QVector<double> data;
QDataStream stream(line);
stream >> data;
```

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to serialize the data as a text. This will make your server and client portable. Sending a binary data over the network is not a good idea. You can create your own text protocol, or use the existing one (like Google Protocol Buffers).

Comment: I'm not down voting you, but disagree with your answer.  Protocol Buffers is a binary protocol.  TCP and UDP are also.

Comment: I agree that G.P.B. is a binary protocol. I meant that one need to use a strictly defined protocol like QDataStream or G.P.B to send data and avoid sending a pure C binary data with the help of reinterpret_cast.