# How to convert QVector<double> to QBytearray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I would like to convert `QVector<double>` to `QBytearray`, and I have no idea on how to do this. 
I tried this but the program crashes:

```
QVector<double> vec;
QByteArray arr = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vec),vec.size());
for(int i = 0; i< vec.size(); i++)
    arr.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vec.data(&numberOfData),sizeof(double));
```

Can someone tell me how to do it properly?

Comment: You'll first have to specify what you want the `QByteArray` to contain. Simply the raw binary data from the vector?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479986/convert-from-qbytearray-to-array-of-double

Comment: @Angew What do you mean? Next i will use Qbytearray to display picture.

Comment: `QVector<double>` is an array of floating-point numbers. `QByteArray` is an array of bytes. You need to specify what you mean with "convert." Store the binary data of the floating-point numbers (as e.g. `memcpy` would do)? Or something else?

Comment: The loop can't make any sense if you don't even use the loop variable to access the element in the vector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass through a native array, so your QByteArray will receive a sequence of contiguous bytes.

```
double *bytes = new double[vec.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
   bytes[i] = vec[i];
}
QByteArray array = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<void*>(bytes));
delete []bytes;
```

Disclaimer: untested code.

--- Update ---

As leemes correctly pointed out, you DON'T need to allocate and copy a byte array, QVector already provides two access functions to raw data. So you can simply use data() and constData().
Please see his response.

Comment: Why do you copy the vector to a raw array if `vec.data()` already gives you a pointer to exactly that?

Comment: Right. I forgot about data() and constData(), I almost never use it.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `QVector::constData` to get a pointer to the (const) raw data contained in the vector. However, you also need to multiply the size by the size of a single entry, i.e. `sizeof(double)`. You don't need a loop afterwards like in your code.

```
QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromRawData(
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vec.constData()),
        sizeof(double) * vec.size()
    );
```

You could also use `QDataStream` to do the conversion, resulting in a much cleaner code, which also takes care of potential [byte ordering issues](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/).

```
QByteArray data;
QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
for (auto x : vec)
    stream << x;
```

Comment: It's shallow copy!

Answer (score 0):

Today this conversion is even simpler:

```
QVector<double> vec;
// populate vector
QByteArray data;
QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << vec;
```

Comment: Will  "<<" flush all the elements in "vec" to the stream?

Comment: I do not use Qt for a couple years, so dunno, but a simple test should give you the answer.

Comment: Someone has just downvoted a simplified syntax answer w/o providing any motivation for downvoting. Sounds like this is retaliatory downvoting or trolling and therefore has no place on SO. This resource is becoming a cesspool day by day.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit annoyed by this too. Building on other answers here, I came up with this:

```
template<typename data_type>
QByteArray toByteArray(data_type data) {
    QByteArray bytes;
    QDataStream stream(&bytes, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream << data;
    return bytes;
}
```

This should let you write the following code:

```
QVector<double> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};
auto bytes = toByteArray(vec);
```

And will also work for other types that support streaming to a QDataStream.